# Why can't my directive inherit a function from its parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I created a directive which is supposed to inherit something from its parent scope.

I used scope{...} , but it just receives regular variables. `function`s don't appear to work.

Also, I'm using Angular 1.4, so I used `"vm = this;"` instead of `"$scope"`:

```js
angular
    .module('player')
    .controller('MediaPlayerController', MediaPlayerController)
    .directive('sessionInfo', sessionInfo);

    function MediaPlayerController($sce, $timeout) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.setSourceIndex = setSourceIndex;
      vm.playerConfig ={};

      vm.session = {
        sessionName: 'SAT',
        sections: [
          {
            sectionId: 0,
            sectionName: 'SAT-1',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("videogular.mp4"), type: "video/mp4" }
            ]
          },
          {
            sectionId: 1,
            sectionName: 'SAT-2',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("big_buck_bunny_720p_h264.mov"), type: 'video/mp4'}
            ]
          }
        ]
      };

      function setSourceIndex(index) {
        vm.playerConfig.sources = vm.session.sections[index].sources;
      };
    }

    function sessionInfo() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          sections: '=',
          setSourceIndex: '&'
        },
        template: '<li ng-repeat="section in sections"><div ng-click="setSourceIndex({{section.sectionId}})">{{section.sectionName}}</div></li>'
      }
    }
```

```html
<div ng-controll="MediaPlayerController as meidaPlayer">
    <div class="playerSide">
      <ul session-info sections="mediaPlayer.session.sections" setSourceIndex="mediaPlayer.setSourceIndex(index)"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: `ng-controll` should be `ng-controller`. As noted in answer below your angular syntax has numerous problems

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues here

- `setSourceIndex` should be written with dashes: `set-source-index`. I'm not even sure it has a purpose here, since you're not calling it from the directive.
- you wrote `meidaPlayer` instead of `mediaPlayer`
- you didn't set a controller for your directive. That controller should then interact with the directive's attributes.

Comment: Can be done without directive controller or link function. Last line isn't totally accurate